# HTTP Error 500.19 in IIS on run ASP .NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, .net-core

I'm trying to run an application (which used to work on another iis)

1) All permissions for writing / reading I gave to all users

2) All services from the section "Application Development Features" I installed

3) When I start the application: > dotnet AppName.dll , It launches and works
[image]

But through the server IIS it does not start.
This is what the IIS says:
HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error

**Module**      nbsp;  IIS Web Core

**Notification**       Unknown

**Handler**        Not yet determined

**Error Code**     0x8007000d

**Config Error**

**Config File**        \?\C:\inetpub\MyServices\ContractNET\web.config

Setting the source:

```
   -1: 
    0:
```

Comment: We need more information about your configuration of IIS.

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: You have to install the "Hosting Bundle Installer". Without this, IIS doesn't understand routing and cannot host your application.

Go to microsoft site "https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.1.0-rc1" and install "Hosting Bundle Installer":

Before installing this you have to install the right version of runtime:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.1.0-rc1
Than install the right version of "Hosting Bundle Installer".